# Writing shortened awk statement in bash profile?

Tags: awk, bash

I want to make a function in my bash profile to shorten:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="\t"}{}'
```

I'd like to be able to type:

```
awk2 '{print $0}'
```

And have it do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="\t"}{print $0}'
```

Unless it detects BEGIN in the input...in which case it would revert to the original awk functioning.

Does anyone have any idea what this function would look like?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy if you use awk's -v instead of a BEGIN block.

```
awk2() {
   awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' "$@"
}
```

The -v is used for variable assignments and does take place before line processing.

Comment: You forgot to detect `BEGIN`.

Comment: You can have multiple `BEGIN` blocks so you can do `awk "BEGIN {FS = OFS = \"\t\"} $@"` as the body of your function.

Comment: What I have right now, which probably isn't that close to working is:

function awk2()
{
if [[ $1 !=~ "BEGIN" ]];
then awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t'$1
fi
}

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, with your second comment, you'll put the filename arguments inside the awk script.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, indeed, though I can't explain how this happens: `function awkt { awk "BEGIN {FS=OFS=\"\\t\"} $@"; }; set -x; awkt '$1=="a" {print $2}' tmp/tabfile.txt` reveals this expansion: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} $1=="a" {print $2}' tmp/tabfile.txt` -- how does bash know that the last argument to the function should NOT be part of the awk script??? I thought only `"$@"` was magical. Is `"anything here $@"` magical too?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson (continued) I guess any `$@` in double quotes acts magically, so `"prefix $@ suffix"` will prepend `prefix[space]` to the first argument and append `[space]suffix` to the last argument.

Comment: @glennjackman: I'd have to do some tests, but I'm pretty sure it's because a quoted `$@` is treated as individual array elements and the magic comes along for free.

Answer (score 0):

An alias would be messy, I recommend you shorten it using a bash function:

```
function awk2() {
    awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" "$@"
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about aliases.